# Jenkins not starting

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, amazon-ec2, cicd

This is the issue - Failed to enable unit: Unit file jenkins.service does not exist

can anyone help me with this issue. Thank you.

I tried again with the previous process and search for this issue. but again it occurs.

https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/linux/ - this is the guide i'm following.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when systemctl daemon is not reloaded to reload new services.
Type this on linux shell with sudo

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

after that try enabling and starting your service, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have installed the Java and jenkins correctly

java -version

sudo systemctl enable jenkins

If you get the output, then please restart the VM or wherever you have installed Jenkins. It should solve the issue. Or close the terminal once and open a new terminal, this also might solve your issue.